# How many objects in my memory with Take extension method in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I use a GenericRepository which has the Get method :

I would like to know if there is a loading difference between following  chunks of code:

```
Expression<Func<PressRelease_ar, bool>> exp = p => p.Id <=5 ; 
lst = Global.uow.PressReleaseRepository_ar
      .Get
      (
         filter : exp, 
         orderBy: n => n.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id)
       ).ToList();
```

And

```
 lst = Global.uow.PressReleaseRepository_ar
          .Get
          (
             orderBy: n => n.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id)
          ).Take(5).ToList();
```

For more details, this is the Get method:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
                                 Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
                                 Func<IQueryable<TEntity>,
                                 IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
                                 string includeProperties = "")
   {

      IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

      if (filter != null) query = query.Where(filter);

      foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                 (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
      {
          query = query.Include(includeProperty);
      }


      if (orderBy != null) return orderBy(query).ToList();
      else return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: You have syntax-errors in your Get-method.

Comment: Your question title is confusing. Eager and lazy loading refers to different approaches to load *navigation properties* of an entity. Your question has nothing to do with loading navigation properties, has it?

Comment: @Slauma : please advice a title. Thanks for your answer, satisfied.

Comment: "How to load data with Take extension method in EF?" or "Why is using Take extension method in EF so slow?" or similar, depending on what causes you to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Get` method causes a query to execute (you are using `ToList()` at the end of the method). This leads to a big difference:

- Your first query looks up all rows with id <= 5 in the database and materializes only those rows as entities. So you get max. 5 objects in memory (given that your smallest id is 1).
- Your second query does not have a filter at all which is applied in SQL. So it sorts the whole table descending by id and then returns the full table and as many objects as there are rows in the table will get materialized in memory. On this in-memory collection you apply `Take(5)` (LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to Entities) which means that you then throw away all objects except the first five.

The second query is bad. `Take(5)` should be performed on your `IQueryable` inside of your `Get` method to make sure that the selection for the first 5 rows happens actually in the database and only those 5 objects get created in memory.